# Matrix sieve theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have derived the following theorem:

Odd positive integer $N=6n-1$ is a prime iff neither of two diophantine equations

$6x^2+(6x-1)y=n$

$6x^2+(6x+1)y=n$

has solution.

Odd positive integer $N=6n+1$ is a prime iff neither of two diophantine equations

$6x^2-2x+(6x-1)y=n$

$6x^2+2x+(6x+1)y=n$

$x=1, 2, 3,..; y=0, 1, 2,...; n=1, 2, 3,...$

has solution.

Theorem allows to find all primes (up to a given limit) since all primes (exept 2 and 3) are in one of two forms $6n-1$ or $6n+1$.

My question is: does exist a general method to determine that a given 
diophantine equation
has

no solution?

Comment: If you mean equations of this kind : They should be easy enough to be decidable. In general however, there is no method to decide whether a diophantine equation has an integer solution (see Hilbert's tenth problem)

Comment: But a warning : That an equation is solveable does not mean that we can decide efficiently whether it has a solution. In the case of the prime numbers, I do not think that this approach is very useful because there are much more efficient methods to check whether a number is prime.

Comment: I wonder: what may be simplier than

Comment: What do you want to do exactly ? Sieving small numbers to generate the first primes ? Or checking larger numbers ?

Comment: I want to check large numbers

Comment: Number of digits approximately ?

Comment: I wonder: what may be simplier than $y=(n-6x^2)/(6x-1)=whole?$

Comment: But you have to check many $x's$. To factor, let's say, a $20$-digit number, I do not think that this approach is efficient.

Comment: my program works up to 10^19     http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/BrowseCategoryOrSearchResults.asp?lngWId=3&blnAuthorSearch=TRUE&lngAuthorId=21687209&strAuthorName=Boris%20Sklyar&txtMaxNumberOfEntriesPerPage=25

Comment: Then, the Adleman-Pomerance-Rumely test will be best, perhaps the slightly faster BPSW-test.

Comment: Run time app. 1 s   - see  http://www.planet-source-code.com/Upload_PSC/ScreenShots/PIC201583550355653.jpg

Comment: Solution of given diophantine equations - see https://www.alpertron.com.ar/JQUAD.HTM

Comment: Are you saying that every integer that fulfills: 6n+1 or 6n-1, is a prime?

Comment: No, not every integer that fulfills: $6n+1$ or $6n-1$, is a prime, but all  numbers (composite and prime) will be (after removing from the set of positive integers all numbers divisible by 2 and all numbers divisible by 3) in one of two forms: $6n-1$ or $6n+1$

Comment: See https://www.academia.edu/13890086/Matrix_sieve_the_easiest_way_to_find_prime_numbers